# Button to run a group of cells

Tags: button, cells

I'm not sure how to create a minimal working example since I don't know how to post code that appears as cells but hopefully my question is simple enough that it won't be necessary. My apologies all the same though.

I have quite a large notebook where in the first few cells I set various quantities and then after that I just want to run the rest of the notebook. Currently I have all the subsequent cells grouped together so that I just need to select the group and then evaluate. Now I would like to create a button that achieves the same result.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I do not want a button to evaluate the whole notebook. I could do it with something like (found on another thread):

```
evalStart := Module[{}, 
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"]];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "EvaluateCells"]];];
Button["do it", evalStart]
```

What I am looking for is a button that evaluates just a group of cells. i.e I want to be able to play around with the first few cells of the notebook and then have a button to run the rest of it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have you seen `InitializationCell`?

Comment: You could produce a button like this by `Button["evaluate Notebook", FrontEndTokenExecute@"EvaluateNotebook"]`. Or you just use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl H`, after you ran `Get@"http://www.mertig.com/shortcuts.m"` and restarted Mathematica.

Comment: So basically you need to run whole notebook right?